# Yii2 Ajax validation isn't working

Tags: ajax, validation, yii2

I am using ajax validation for unique field and it's not working.
In my usercontroller it works but in this sitecontroller doesn't.

Can anyone help me for this?

This is my Controller

```
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm;
use frontend\models\ResetPasswordForm;
use frontend\models\SignupForm;
use frontend\models\User;
use frontend\models\UserSeacrh;
use frontend\models\ContactForm;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout', 'signup'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['signup'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }



    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays contact page.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'There was an error sending email.');
            }

            return $this->refresh();
        } else {
            return $this->render('contact', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays about page.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionAbout()
    {
        return $this->render('about');
    }

    /**
     * Signs user up.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionSignup()
    {
        $model = new SignupForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                    return $this->goHome();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('signup', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    public function actionValidation()
    {
        $model = new User();

        if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
        {
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Requests password reset.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionRequestPasswordReset()
    {
        $model = new PasswordResetRequestForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail()) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Check your email for further instructions.');

                return $this->goHome();
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Sorry, we are unable to reset password for email provided.');
            }
        }

        return $this->render('requestPasswordResetToken', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Resets password.
     *
     * @param string $token
     * @return mixed
     * @throws BadRequestHttpException
     */
    public function actionResetPassword($token)
    {
        try {
            $model = new ResetPasswordForm($token);
        } catch (InvalidParamException $e) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException($e->getMessage());
        }

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate() && $model->resetPassword()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'New password was saved.');

            return $this->goHome();
        }

        return $this->render('resetPassword', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is my model

```
<?php

namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $lastname
 * @property string $email
 * @property integer $phone
 * @property string $notes
 * @property string $company
 * @property string $password_hash
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property integer $status
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property integer $updated_at
 * @property string $country
 * @property string $state
 * @property string $city
 * @property string $language
 * @property integer $salary
 * @property string $hiredate
 * @property string $birthday
 * @property string $address
 * @property string $dismission
 */
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    public function fields()
    {
        return [
            'id','status'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['username', 'unique'],
            [['username', 'name', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone', 'password_hash'], 'required'],
            [['phone', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'salary'], 'integer'],
            [['hiredate', 'birthday', 'dismission'], 'safe'],
            [['username', 'name', 'lastname', 'email', 'notes', 'company', 'password_hash', 'auth_key', 'country', 'state', 'city', 'language', 'address'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'lastname' => 'Lastname',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'phone' => 'Phone',
            'notes' => 'Notes',
            'company' => 'Company',
            'password_hash' => 'Password Hash',
            'auth_key' => 'Auth Key',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
            'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
            'country' => 'Country',
            'state' => 'State',
            'city' => 'City',
            'language' => 'Language',
            'salary' => 'Salary',
            'hiredate' => 'Hiredate',
            'birthday' => 'Birthday',
            'address' => 'Address',
            'dismission' => 'Dismission',
        ];
    }
}
```

This is my view

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model \frontend\models\SignupForm */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use frontend\models\Countries;
use frontend\models\States;
use frontend\models\Cities;
use yii\helpers\Url;

$this->title = 'Signup';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-signup">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>Please fill out the following fields to signup:</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup', 'enableAjaxValidation' => true, 'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute('site/validation')]); ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'lastname')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'company')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'password_hash')->passwordInput()->label('Password') ?>


                <?= $form->field($model, 'country')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Countries::find()->all(),'id','name'), 
                [
                    'prompt' => 'Страна', 
                    'onchange' => '
                        $.post( "../states/lists?id='.'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                        $( "select#signupform-state" ).html( data );
                        });'
                ]); ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'state')->dropDownList([], 
                [
                    'prompt' => 'Регион',
                    'onchange' => '
                        $.post( "../cities/lists?id='.'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                        $( "select#signupform-city" ).html( data );
                        });'
                ]); ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'city')->dropDownList([],[ 'prompt' => 'Город' ]); ?>


                <?= $form->field($model, 'language')->dropDownList([
                    '1' => 'Русский',
                    '2' => 'English',
                    '3' => 'Turkce',
                ]); ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
                </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add 'enableClientValidation' => false in your form and try?

Comment: Is there a reason for method `fields()` in your model?

Comment: @Manikandan S , I added and it's not working

Comment: @Bizley , i deleted that its'not helped

Comment: add `signUpForm.php`.

Comment: @Bakhtiyar Ok. can you check your browser developer tool network tab is there any request is going on or not and if yes what is that request response?

Comment: @Manikandan S , i checked and it's not sends request

Comment: @Bakhtiyar hmm strange. form submitting is blocked from your javascript code. Please double check your js codes once.

Answer (score 0):

**SiteController.php**

```
public function actionSignup()
{
    $model = new SignupForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
        if ($user = $model->signup()) {
            if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                return $this->goHome();
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('signup', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

**SignUpForm.php**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['username', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['username', 'required'],
        ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
        ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],

        ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['email', 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['email', 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],

        ['password', 'required'],
        ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],
    ];
}

/**
 * Signs user up.
 *
 * @return User|null the saved model or null if saving fails
 */
public function signup()
{
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return null;
    }

    $user = new User();
    $user->username = $this->username;
    $user->email = $this->email;
    $user->setPassword($this->password);
    $user->generateAuthKey();

    return $user->save() ? $user : null;
}
```

**signup.php**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup', 'enableAjaxValidation' => true]); ?>
```